# How to loop through 2 lists and combine the results in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to loop through 2 lists and combine the results and write that to a file, however I could find a method to do this yet.

```
hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']
ips = ['ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3']
filename = 'devicelist.txt'

with open(filename, 'w') as out_file:
    for i in ips:
        for h in hosts:
            out_file.write(h + ' - ' + i + '\n')
```

This basically runs through every possible combination, but that's not the result I'm looking for.
What I'm looking is like this:

```
host1 - ip1
host2 - ip2
host3 - ip3
```

Comment: I read your question again. it seems you are making a list of lists that is usually done with list comprehension see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507319/python-list-comprehension-list-of-lists

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this code is that you're first looping over one list, and then over the other. You can easily take care of this by combining both using the `zip` function. This combines two lists like this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = zip(a,b)
```

here

```
c = [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Now doing this:

```
hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']
ips = ['ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3']

#if the lists don't have the same length, you'll get an incomplete list here!
output = zip(hosts, ips)
```

Gets you a combined list that you can write to your file using:

```
with open('devicelist.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for i in output:
          out_file.write('{} - {} \n'.format(i[0], i[1]))
```

the `'{}'.format(x)` outputs a string with x instead of the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You have two lists of same length,
So it is just a piece of cake.

You can do it like this,

```
filename = 'devicelist.txt' 
open(filename, 'w') # Creates File.
hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']
ips = ['ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3']
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
       for i in range(len(hosts)):
            f.write(hosts[i]+' - '+ips[i])
```

This should do the Job!

> Happy Coding!!

Answer (score -1):

If the two arrays have the same length you can do:

```
for i in xrange(length):  # length is any of the arrays length
    out_file.write(hosts[i] + ' - ' + ips[i] + '\n')
```

this can be simpified to:

```
newList = [hosts[i] + ' - ' + ips[i] + '\n' for i in xrange(length)]

with open(filename, 'w') as out_file:
    for element in newList:
            out_file.write(element)
```

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel) answer for better methods and more explanation.

Comment: i reread his question and he his making list of lists. a list comprehension would be ideal

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution:

```
hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']
ips = ['ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3']

assert len(hosts) == len(ips) # check that the 2 list are the same lenght

with open('devicelist.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for i in xrange(len(ips)):
        out_file.write(hosts[i] + ' - ' + ips[i] + '\n')
```