# To build upon this: list comprehension for a list of uneven lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

[Python: List comprehension list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507319/python-list-comprehension-list-of-lists)

So far I have seen that list comprehension works really well for matrices and even tuple sublists:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

yet I do not think I have seen a good solution to the uneven sublist situation:

```
x = [[[[34, 21], [20, 21],[24, 212],[20, 21],[16, 12],[840, 190],[-406, 188],[-410, 185]],[[220, 204],[229, 167],[234, 100],[231, 150],[236, 156],[232, 1362],[254, 196],[256, 962],[258, 878],[254, 776],[264, -50],[271, -410]],[[2326, 1984],[2412, 1958],[2540, 1896],[4506, 869]]]]
```

How would I run a function in a manner similar to list comprehension over the tuples that changes and replaces all of their values? Supposing the function to be used as the following:

```
def tuplFun(x1, y1):
    a = x1 / 2 * 30.0 - 80.0
    b = math.atan(math.sinh(math.pi * (1 - 2 * y1 / 4)))
    return (a, b)
```

Please pardon if I use the incorrect terminology since I am not a regular developer or programmer. This is a matter of understanding the limitations of list comprehensions and the proper way to address different scenarios that exist within data sets.

Thank you.

Comment: So you want a comprehension to build a list like the one in the question? What would be the construction logic behind the list?

Comment: There is no transformation of the structuring of the data in question, instead only the values are updated or changed. The data originates from a graphics program, whereby we are seeing lines in vector form. For some reason, I think the unevenness of the sublists (individual line data) makes the application of comprehensions difficult. Possibly a for loop or recursion/loop combination to apply the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's start working with 'the more difficult' `x` you have given:

```
x = [[[[34, 21], [20, 21],[24, 212],[20, 21],[16, 12],[840, 190],[-406, 188],[-410, 185]],[[220, 204],[229, 167],[234, 100],[231, 150],[236, 156],[232, 1362],[254, 196],[256, 962],[258, 878],[254, 776],[264, -50],[271, -410]],[[2326, 1984],[2412, 1958],[2540, 1896],[4506, 869]]]]
```

I will define another `tupl2Fun(x1, y1)` for the sake of simplicity because your `tuplFun(x1, y1)` is not defined for some `x1, y1`:

```
def tupl2Fun(x1, y1):
    a = x1 - 1
    b = y1 + 1
    return [a, b]
```

What you want is a [nested list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list). There are two ways to do it:

```
def nested_list_comprehension1(x):
    #replaces every cell of x dynamically
    for a in x:
        for b in a:
            for c in b:
                c[0], c[1] = tupl2Fun(c[0], c[1])

def nested_list_comprehension2(x):
    #return copy of x replaced how you want
    return [[[[tupl2Fun(c[0], c[1]) for c in b] for b in a] for a in x]]

print('initial value of x is: \n', x)
nested_list_comprehension1(x)
print('after applying ''nested_list_comprehension1(x)'' new value of x is: \n', x)
print(nested_list_comprehension2(x))
print('the output of ''nested_list_comprehension2(x)'' is: \n', x)
print('current value of x is: \n', x)
```

You would also like to refuse doing three loops manually in case you don't know depth of your list. In this case use of recursive function is required:

```
def replacer(array):
    if type(array[0]) is not list:
        return tupl2Fun(array[0], array[1])
    else: return [replacer(n) for n in array]

    print('the output of ''replacer(x)'' is:')
    print(replacer(x))
```

This will check if first item of your list is another list and if it's not, apply your function. Otherwise, the same checks will be done for each item.

#### Output of replacer(x):

```
[[[[33, 22], [19, 22], [23, 213], [19, 22], [15, 13], [839, 191], [-407, 189], [-411, 186]], [[219, 205], [228, 168], [233, 101], [230, 151], [235, 157], [231, 1363], [253, 197], [255, 963], [257, 879], [253, 777], [263, -49], [270, -409]], [[2325, 1985], [2411, 1959], [2539, 1897], [4505, 870]]]]
```

Comment: Very nice solution.